# The picture is not displaying in my page (403 error)

Tags: laravel, ftp

I put my website online, and the images are not showing. So I went to the site and went to the developer console.

The following error is displayed:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()

However, when I tried my site in localhost, everything was showing normally.
When I copy/past the img src in my code (using the developer tool) into the my internet URL, I've an

> forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource.

So do I need to edit something somewhere to display the images? Do I have to modify any rights?

NB: I'm using OVH.

EDIT: There is the code I use to store the picture and the one I use to display the picture :

```
protected function saveFiles($idArticle, $file)
{
    $article = Article::where('id_article',$idArticle)->firstOrFail();
    $path = 'public/documents/articles/' . $idArticle . '/' . $article->titre;
    $fileName = $idArticle.'-'.$article->titre.'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $file->storeAs($path, $fileName); 
}
```

In another function I'm doing that :

```
$data = array();
$path = 'public/documents/articles/';
$files = Storage::files($path.$editer_article->id_article . '/' . $editer_article->titre);
$data[$editer_article->id_article] = url(Storage::url($files[0])); 
return view('test', ['data' => $data]);
```

This is inside my controller. Inside my view I'm doing :

```
<img src="{{ $data[$article_carousel->id_article] }}" class="d-block w-100" alt="{{$article_carousel->titre}}"/>
```

As I said, this is working in local, but not online.

Comment: are the images locally stored, or it is from sites. + what code u using to set the image src in codes.?

Comment: What content management system do you use and are you hosting that on nginx or apache? If you use wordpress, please check: https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-image-upload-issue-in-wordpress/#:~:text=First%2C%20connect%20to%20your%20website,the%20file%20permissions%20dialog%20box.

Comment: I'm not using wordpress. I store the picture in my server. I can access the files using the FTP explorer. I'm going to edit my question to add my code for the image.

Comment: you will need to make sure that the storage folder is readable by the webserver user. Accomplishing that will vary by your hosting setup.

Comment: I did a storage link. It display the picture into the storage folder but there is also this storage folder into my public folder (thanks to the symbolic link). I'm really lost there